# Chromecast chrome resolution/window size

Tags: chromecast

I have a custom receiver and using it to cast an HTML dashboard. Everything works great except for the resolution. It looks like the chrome browser (on the chromecast) is displaying at a very low resolution.

It looks like the TV is still getting the feed at 1080p but the browser is zooming in or something like that.

If I just draw a box 1900px wide on the screen about half of it is chopped off. Is there anyway to control the display height/width of the chrome browser running on the chrome cast?

Comment: Looks like this is related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18790621/why-does-the-chromecast-client-declare-its-height-and-width-as-720p-to-the-recei?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

It is 1280x720 but it is best to query for the window size within your JavaScript so if in future things change, your code is still accommodating for that. You also might want to take into account the possibility of overscan on TVs.